# Склоняемость названий на примере кошачьего корма

Tags: падежи, названия

Мой кот любит "Феликс" или "Феликса"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что в данном случае это название противопоставляется человеку с таким именем, поэтому я бы тут сказал *в винительном падеже (любит Феликс).* Однако вот другая фраза: *Пора сходить за "Феликс**ом**".* Здесь, зная контекст или видя написанное с кавычками, легко понять, что кто-то хочет сходить за таким кормом, а вообще, можно то же сказать и про человека.

Comment: А есть ли смысл прибегать к винительному падежу, если в творительном всё равно слово будет менять окончание?

Comment: Мне интуиция подсказывает, что именно так надо. Александр правильно сказал: надо склонять как неодушевлённое несчётное существительное. Вот в последнем его примере с бонусами в быту был бы как раз уместным родительный падеж.

Comment: Да, я подпал под влияние общей словесной схемы рекламщиков; если же одновременно эксплуатировать визуальный образ кота Феликса (вместо изображения пачки корма), то "бонусы" были бы именно "от Феликса (кота)".

Comment: А-а, это корм по имени кота! Я просто вообще был не в теме.))

Comment: Артем, просто для сведения. "Феликс" — двойная вкуснятина; так вкусно, что усики оближешь; аппетитные кусочки; хрустящее лакомство. https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC+%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjn1pSW0aHoAhVJs4sKHcgLCA8QsAR6BAgKEAE&biw=1366&bih=657

Comment: Спасибо, Римма)

Comment: В более ранней рекламной компании на ТВ  Феликс был мультяшный кот, который откликался на это имя и бежал обедать. http://www.advertology.ru/index.php?name=Media&op=MediaShow&id=16362#media_16362

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akDz3nfDziw

Answer (score 2):

В этом примере достаточно склонять название как неодушевленное несчетное существительное (винительный падеж совпадает с именительным): любит "*Феликс*", добавлю ему "*Феликса(-у)*"... Тип склонения здесь соответствует видовому наименованию "*корм*". Не склоняется такое название только в рекламных словооборотах типа "бонусы от [правообладателя торговой марки] Феликс".